# Can't output array like i want (PHP) array output manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

Hello I have to create the following Array

```
{{x: 140224, y: 50.1},{x: 140225, y: 50.0},{x: 140226, y: 50.0},{x: 140227, y: 50.0},{x: 140228, y: 50.1},{x: 140229, y: 50.0},{x: 140230, y: 50.0},{x: 140231, y: 50.0},{x: 140232, y: 50.0},{x: 140233, y: 50.0},{x: 140234, y: 50.0},{x: 140235, y: 50.0},{x: 140236, y: 50.0},{x: 140237, y: 50.0},{x: 140238, y: 50.0},{x: 140239, y: 50.0},{x: 140240, y: 50.0},{x: 140241, y: 50.0},{x: 140242, y: 50.0},{x: 140243, y: 50.0},{x: 140244, y: 50.0}}
```

without the first { element[0] and the last } so it should look like this

```
{x: 140224, y: 50.1},{x: 140225, y: 50.0},{x: 140226, y: 50.0},{x: 140227, y: 50.0},{x: 140228, y: 50.1},{x: 140229, y: 50.0},{x: 140230, y: 50.0},{x: 140231, y: 50.0},{x: 140232, y: 50.0},{x: 140233, y: 50.0},{x: 140234, y: 50.0},{x: 140235, y: 50.0},{x: 140236, y: 50.0},{x: 140237, y: 50.0},{x: 140238, y: 50.0},{x: 140239, y: 50.0},{x: 140240, y: 50.0},{x: 140241, y: 50.0},{x: 140242, y: 50.0},{x: 140243, y: 50.0},{x: 140244, y: 50.0}
```

The code I have to produce this string:

```
 $arraytime[] = array('x: ' . $measurement[2] . ', y: ' . $measurement[12]);

$js_arraytime = json_encode($arraytime);
$js_arraytime = str_replace('"', '' ,$js_arraytime);//
$js_arraytime = str_replace("[", '{', $js_arraytime);
$js_arraytime = str_replace("]", '}', $js_arraytime); 

echo $js_arraytime;
```

if i try to replace $js_arraytime[0] with something else every first element of an array is changing. Can someone please help me out

Comment: Can't you use `array_pop( $arraytime )` and `array_shift( $arraytime )` to knock off the first and last elements before json_encoding?

Comment: Tried, but didn't work giving me the output x: 140224, y: 50.1{{x: 140225, y: 50.0},{x: 140226, y: 50.0},{x: 140227, y: 50.0},{x: 140228, y: 50.1},{x: 140229, y: 50.0},{x: 140230, y: 50.0}

Comment: 1) this is not an array in the way you wrote it. 2) even if you would have an array of objects, you still will have `[{x: 140224, y: 50.1},{x: 140225, y: 50.0},...]`

Comment: Can you help me on teamviewer perhaps?

Comment: You are creating array inside of array here `$arraytime[] = array('x: ' . $measurement[2] . ', y: ' . $measurement[12]);` look on my edited answer

Comment: And how do i fix this? I noticed that i guess :P

Comment: Chris thanks for your help but look on my answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code and output you have posted, you can do what you want with simple string manipulation, but first you have to get rid of the inner arrays.

Change this line:

```
$arraytime[] = array('x: ' . $measurement[2] . ', y: ' . $measurement[12]);
```

to:

```
$arraytime[] = 'x: ' . $measurement[2] . ', y: ' . $measurement[12];
```

Then use `implode()` to turn the array into a string:

```
/* Set up sample array */
$arraytime = array ('x: 140224, y: 50.1',
                    'x: 140225, y: 50.0',
                    'x: 140226, y: 50.0',
                    'x: 140227, y: 50.0');

$js_arraytime = '{' . implode ('},{', $arraytime) . '}';

echo $js_arraytime;
```

Output:

```
{x: 140224, y: 50.1},{x: 140225, y: 50.0},{x: 140226, y: 50.0},{x: 140227, y: 50.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this `substr($js_arraytime, 1,-1);`

Comment: It is giving me the following array: x: 140224, y: 50.1{{x: 140225, y: 50.0},{x: 140226, y: 50.0},{x: 140227, y: 50.0},{x: 140228, y: 50.1},{x: 140229, y: 50.0},{x: 140230, y: 50.0}} Now the problem just moved 1 element.

Comment: $arraytime[] = 'x: ' . $measurement[2] . ', y: ' . $measurement[12]; Is giving me this output..
{x: 140224, y: 50.1,x: 140225, y: 50.0,x: 140226, y: 50.0,x: 140227, y: 50.0,x: 140228, y: 50.1,x: 140229, y: 50.0,x: 140230, y: 50.0,x: 140231, y: 50.0,x: 140232, y: 50.0,x: 140233, y: 50.0,x: 140234, y: 50.0,x: 140235, y: 50.0,x: 140236, y: 50.0,x: 140237, y: 50.0,x: 140238, y: 50.0,x: 140239, y: 50.0,x: 140240, y: 50.0,x: 140241, y: 50.0,x: 140242, y: 50.0,x: 140243, y: 50.0,x: 140244, y: 50.0}

Comment: but i need it like this:

  { x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 450 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 414 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 02, 1), y: 520 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 03, 1), y: 460 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 04, 1), y: 450 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 05, 1), y: 500 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 06, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 07, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 08, 1), y: 410 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 09, 1), y: 500 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 10, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 11, 1), y: 510 }

Comment: how about this `substr($js_arraytime, 1,-1);` @RafaelvandenBerg

Comment: Does nothing :/ can someone help on teamviewer perhaps? ID:743 726 339 Pass:7624

Comment: Do you echo it? `echo substr($js_arraytime, 1,-1);`

Comment: It worked, I am rid of the last } but now i have a string which should work in my graph but it is displaying nothing :/

Comment: @RafaelvandenBerg what do you mean by `graph` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to utilize object in `json_encode` instead of a array with a string and then use `str_replace` for removing the `[` chars.

```
$arraytime[] = array('x' => $measurement[2], 'y' => $measurement[12]);

$js_arraytime = json_encode($arraytime);
$js_arraytime = str_replace(array('[',']','"'), '', $js_arraytime);

echo $js_arraytime;
```